# How to remove duplicate points based on other attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, standard-license-level

I have a point dataset of hundreds of thousands of points (zip+4s), many of which share the same value for one attribute (zip+4), but have different values for other attributes (ex: address). In other words, each zip+4 is represented by multiple points at different addresses. I need a dataset that has only one record for each zip+4. In the past, I have simply dissolved the entire dataset by zip+4 and ended up with multi-point features. This, however is starting to cause problems down the line, because I need the location of each zip+4 to be unique - and if a single zip+4 crosses into multiple cities or counties, it gives me issues.

I have gotten as far as dissolving them into smaller multi-point features by city/county, so that each unique combination of zip+4, city, and county is represented by it's own multi-point feature (and I retained a count attribute of how many points make up each multi-point feature). Now how do I get rid of all but the one record for each zip+4 that has the most points in it?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Delete Identical](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000053000000) tool from the "Data Management" toolbox, you can specify by which fields to compare/delete records.

Or perhaps, [Find Identical](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000054000000) so you can select different fields and view/choose the correct records to be deleted before taking them away.

Comment: I don't think Delete Identical works because I can't say "if the count value is less than the max count value for that zip4, delete it." I don't want to just delete some of them, I want to make sure I'm deleting the right ones.

Comment: I think you will need to convert multipoint into point features. Do all of the points/address have the same attribute for zip+4, if so then remove all fields except zip+4, buffer by a very small number & dissolve then use the surviving centroid by *feature to point* http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003m000000. Note: dissolving a very large dataset causes problems (I've seen three posts about it recently) and it may be necessary to *Dice* http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000037000000 before doing it.